# What is a good, short, word to describe a software engineer?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology, software

What should I call a person who write software, computer programs ? I know he/she is a software engineer, can I call him/her as "Coder"?

Comment: @hippietrail: Was there any problem with my question?

Comment: No it was a good question. I just added some tags I thought were appropriate.

Comment: I can think of a few short words that have been directed at me over the years, but I don't think that's what you mean.

Comment: "Geek" is about as short as you're liable to get.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In increasing order of formality:

- *Coder* refers to someone who engages in the act of writing source code, and has a very casual, possibly even negative connotation.
- *Programmer* refers to someone who writes software, which has a neutral connotation.
- *Developer* or *dev* refers to someone who *develops* software, which may or may not involve actually writing it, but probably does.
- *Software engineer* and *computer scientist* are more formal terms for those with degrees or other professional qualifications.
- *SE* is a commonly used abbreviation in speech for a software engineer, but *CS* is only used for *computer science* itself, not the people who practice it.

Comment: I never thought of coder as having a negative connotation. "Code monkey", on the other hand, is often used as a derogatory term.

Comment: Or 'Code droid'.

Comment: ...but you would probably not want to use the abbreviation _SE_ on StackExchange sites, because everyone would think you refer to StackExchange...

Comment: so, 'dev' is the shortest word

Comment: "Programmer" sounds quaint to me - not a word we developers would use among ourselves, but one which might have more currency with a non-technical audience, especially when prefixed with *computer*: "That's right Grandma - I'm a *computer programmer*..."

Comment: @Anwar: as an abbreviation, 'dev' ranks as very informal.  I usually come across it as part of a compound, such as "Dev Engineer" (distinguishing someone working on the main codebase from, say, a Tools Engineer or a Test Engineer).

Comment: @Rhodri: agree on the informality of 'dev'. Where I work, we would use the full word *developer* to describe ourselves, and only use *dev* as a qualifier: 'dev system', 'dev tools', etc. To be described as 'devs' sounds almost flippant, like calling builders 'brickies' or managers 'suits'

Comment: "Computer scientist" is a legitimate term, but not generally used for people who write code for a living.

Comment: `terms for those with degrees` Does this mean I should not call myself a software engineer if I do not have a degree?

Comment: @John Isaacks - If you haven't every seriously studied software engineering on your own either, probably not. Anyone who claims that title and can't talk about the big-O time behavior or cohesion and coupling of his program is a fraud.

Comment: Programmer is more formal than coder, but I still don't really like it. A lot of the work I do doesn't involve writing code, but designing systems and planning out how and when each component will be built (even when it's just _my_ part of the project I'm planning). Personally I prefer the full "Software Developer." It's not confused with other kinds of developers, and although it's long to type out, it's somewhat quick to say. I feel that all the time I've invested to learn what I know deserves the extra two syllables. "Engineer" and "Scientist" are a little over the top, though.

Comment: @Kop, ah I see. Nice one. ;-)

Comment: Although they have much in common, a computer scientist is *not* a software engineer.  In a nutshell, Computer Science is the branch of Mathematics that enquires, "What can be (efficiently) procedurally computed?"  Mathematicians have been studying this in earnest since before the first computer was ever built.

Comment: Also Introvert. ;)

Comment: I suspect that most "real" programmers would consider "coder" to be dismissive.

Answer (score 10):

The best single-word answer especially if they're writing the software is ***[programmer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/programmer)***. But ***[developer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/developer)*** is just as good and blurs the lines beyond programming into things such as beta testing or internationalization.

Multi-word terms sound more formal and are usually more specific. As well as your ***[software engineer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/software_engineer)*** there is also ***computer scientist***.

***[Coder](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coder)*** is a word a lot of programmers would use to self-describe but I've learned from this discussion that among some people at least it carries a negative connotation I had never been previously aware of.

Comment: In my mind, "computer scientist" isn't really akin to "software engineer". A computer scientist would study the science of computation and theoretically might never touch a PC or learn a programming language.

Comment: I kind of get annoyed when people use the term "computer scientist" as a synonym for "programmer". Like, I freely describe myself as a programmer or developer, but would never refer to myself as a computer scientist. (he and I posted at the same time)

Comment: Indeed they are very different. Personally I don't feel like a scientist or an engineer. Maybe that's why I prefer programmer. Anyway I do feel these are the terms that should be known to a person that would ask such a question since the uninitiated layperson wouldn't know the differences and think of them all as programmers )-:

Comment: I wouldn't say *Coder* was at all negative, but it only describes one aspect of software engineering. An architect (of buildings) might accurately describe themselves as a *draughtsman*, but they also use other disciplines when designing a building.

Answer (score 7):

"Hacker" used to be the preferred term, back before stupid newspaper folks got hold of it and decided to use it exclusively for malicious people who break into networked computers. Evidentally, those were the only kinds of hackers they had any interest in. :-(

We fought this for a while, but it is really tough to win a war of words with people who buy ink by the barrel.

So now, as the other answers indicate, we are sort of casting about for new terms. Where I work, the term "developer" is used. However, if you use that among the general public, people might think you are talking about someone who builds houses for a living. So I generally just say "Software Engineer". If eyes cross, I elaborate this way: "I spend my days telling computers what to do. Then they tell me to F-off, and I spend the rest of the day trying to figure out why."

Comment: There's a silver lining to people misunderstanding the term "hacker". Now it makes a useful shibboleth.

Comment: +1 just for this: "...it is really tough to win a war of words with people who buy ink by the barrel."

Comment: @mwolfe02 - Thanks for the upvote, but I didn't make it up. People can't seem to decide on who did though, so perhaps I should claim it. :-)

Comment: My favorite response to that last line so far was from a teacher, who said, "That's my job too!"

Answer (score 6):

Generally the preferred term would be *programmer*. Coder has a negative implication: that the person only does unchallenging, trivial work.

By the way, "Engineer" in some places has a legal meaning, that requires some sort of government certification. It depends on the state or the country, but it may be against to law to call yourself an engineer if you don't have such a certification. As far as I know, no such certification process exists anywhere for a "software engineer", nonetheless it would still be illegal to use the word "engineer."

Comment: I disagree that *coder* has a negative implication. Most of my programmer friends describe themselves as coders though personally I always say I am a *programmer*. In the past when it was my job I sometimes called myself a *developer* but it felt a bit too grandiose.

Comment: @hippietrail I'm sure it depends on the locale and group. *Coder* is definitely negative among most of the developers/programmers I work and network with. It's used to describe someone who can write basic functions and such but can't work above that level: they just write code

Comment: Yes maybe you should edit your answer to "has a negative implication" to "may have a negative implication". Of my friends who started programming professionally, the one who now earns the most money always refers to himself as *coder* but I accept from yourself and Jon that some people in some places must use the term negatively.

Comment: I agree with hippietrail, developer is also a good choice.

Comment: In the US it would be illegal to use the word "engineer" or "engineering" in the name of a business: it implies being a licensed [Professional Engineer (P.E.)](https://www.nspe.org/resources/licensure/what-pe).

Answer (score 5):

I'm a software engineer, and in my experience, using the term *dev* (short for "*developer*) or *eng* (short for engineer) are both common things to say, and people I have worked with seem to be fine with both terms.

Answer (score 0):

You can call them very shortly as "SE-DEV"  means software engineer in develop department.. 
I think thats really cool for calling rather than **coder or programmer**

Answer (score 0):

There is a big discussion on the subject. it is hard to attribute the term engineering to this discipline, as compared to other hard or traditional engineering fields, we sometimes lack of that little "exact" part the other science have. most topics or areas in software engineering are far to be exact science. perhaps thats why some legislation don't give us the same level of attributions as to other engineers.

As for the part is we should call somebody developer, programmer or software engineering. I think the field of SE goes beyond simply coding, or developing. it also deals with, requirements, design, management, QA, continuous improvement, cost and effort estimation, planning, etc, etc. so using the term SE indiscriminately its a risky business. its like calling architect or civil engineer to a bricklayer (no offense both are needed to make a house or a bridge).

Right now there is a lot of effort to approach to that exact part, but we still got a long way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The question suggested but not explicitly asked here is, who is the engineer?
In the field of computer systems building, a computer systems engineer, for example, deals with the assembly material (hardware) and instructions (software, low-level mostly) to create its system components from scratch, while a software engineer comes to link and analyze these systems (software and selective hardware) in accordance with company and market needs for software development. A coder or programmer deals with software and programming language development only.

Answer (score -1):

I notice that a few years ago the word *programmer* was the only widely used word. Now the trend is to use *developer*. I'm not a native English speaker, but I hate the word *developer* because the obvious question is, “What the hell does the developer develop?”

Another way to express my point is: If programmers build programs, can we say that developers build “develops”?

Sorry for the irony, but the word *developer* doesn't mean anything for people outside the software industry.

I consider myself a *programmer*, not a *developer* or a *coder*.

Comment: Programmer doesn't just refer to computer programmers; one could also be a broadcast programmer, amongst other things. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_programming